# Threejs FBXLoader is scaling in 100

Tags: three.js

I'm using the example webgl_loader_fbx.
When I import my object, it's working, but it's scaling in 100.

Why does not it stay in the original size?

I'm using threejs release r100

```
var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
loader.load( 'untitled.fbx', function ( object ) {
    scene.add( object );
    console.log(object.children[0]);
} );
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edited. please help me!

Comment: I could scale the object of the group, but the position of the child remains great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at your scene units in Blender. Did you change the scale to something besides `1.00`?

[image]:

If not, you can scale your sphere in the FBX Export panel to `0.01`:

[image]

You can read more details about scaling your exports in the [FBX Exporter documentation](https://digitalrune.github.io/DigitalRune-Documentation/html/6f749972-9cb2-4274-b283-c327ba45e379.htm#Units)

Comment: Thanks my friend! I changed the exporter to 0.01 and it worked

Comment: I think it's an issue with the blender exporter. If you upgrade to blender 2.80 you can export as glTF instead, that generally recommended over FBX if possible.